# form associated with the model not submitting to database

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm newbie in the Python. I made a landing page that has a form with sending a phone number, but it does not get into the database. Form associated with the model

Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField


class CallOrder(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, verbose_name='First name')
    phone = PhoneNumberField(null=False, blank=False, unique=False, verbose_name='Phone')
    email_field = models.EmailField(blank=True, verbose_name='Email')
    message = models.TextField(max_length=400, blank=True, verbose_name='Comments')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Created at')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Call order'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Call orders'
```

Forms.py (CallOrderForm):

```
from django import forms
from repair_service.models import CallOrder

    class CallOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = CallOrder
            fields = ['first_name', 'phone', 'email_field', 'message']
            widgets = {
                'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                'phone': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                'email_field': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                'message': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': '3'}),
            }
```

Views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import CallOrderForm


def base(request):
    header_menu_button = {'': 'Home', 'qui_sommes_nous': 'Qui sommes nous', 'nos_services': 'Nos services', 'avis': 'Avis', 'contacts': 'Contacts', 'faq': 'FAQ', 'partenaires': 'Partenaires'}
    content_body = {'qui_sommes_nous': 'qui_sommes_nous_content', 'nos_services': 'nos_services_content', 'avis': 'avis_content', 'contacts': 'contacts_content', 'faq': 'faq_content', 'partenaires': 'partenaires_content'}
    form = CallOrderForm()
    return render(request=request, template_name='repair_service/base.html', context={'title': 'Mr.Ginzby', 'header_menu_button': header_menu_button, 'content_body': content_body, 'form': form})

def call_back(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CallOrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
        form = CallOrderForm()
    return render(request, 'repair_service/base.html', {'form': form})
```

Html:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}<br>
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <div class="d-grid gap-2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: If the view you submit the form to is base, then you are not handling the form submit at all. You only handle it in the call_back view, and the action of the form is to send it to the page it is on, which won't work on the base view.  On the other hand, if you know that, and it's the call_back view that isn't working, can you provide the CallOrderForm, please?

Comment: @SamSparx 
Added forms.py with  class CallOrderForm

Comment: Can you please also share urls for both the views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django always takes current page route, form's data is not even goes to `call_back` view, one way to solve the problem is to specify the url name in the `action` attribute of form, so that the data could go to `call_back` view, but I have another approach of making single view instead of two views, so:

views.py:

```py
def base(request):
    context='' # for the error local variable `context` referenced before assignment.
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CallOrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else: # Get condition
        header_menu_button = {'': 'Home', 'qui_sommes_nous': 'Qui sommes nous', 'nos_services': 'Nos services', 'avis': 'Avis', 'contacts': 'Contacts', 'faq': 'FAQ', 'partenaires': 'Partenaires'}
        content_body = {'qui_sommes_nous': 'qui_sommes_nous_content', 'nos_services': 'nos_services_content', 'avis': 'avis_content', 'contacts': 'contacts_content', 'faq': 'faq_content', 'partenaires': 'partenaires_content'}
        form = CallOrderForm()
        context={'title': 'Mr.Ginzby', 'header_menu_button': header_menu_button, 'content_body': content_body, 'form': form}
        
    return render(request, 'repair_service/base.html', context)
```

Remove that `call_back` view.