# Django "if request.method == 'POST':" returns False

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm making Django app and I have an issue, I've never had problem with before. As always in form view, I'm checking if request.method == 'POST' but somehow it returns False,

My code looks like that:

```
def recipe_create_view(request):
    context = {}

    form = RecipeForm(request.POST or None)
    IngredientFormset = formset_factory(IngredientForm)
    formset = IngredientFormset(request.POST or None)

    context['form'] = form
    context['formset']  = formset

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            if formset.is_valid():
                form.save()
                print("made a recipe")
                
                for form in formset:
                    child = form.save(commit=False)
                    child.recipe = parent
                    child.save()
                    print("made a Ingredient")
            else:
                print("formset is not valid")
        else:
            print("form is not valid")
    else:
        print("request method is not correct")

    return render(request, 'recipes/create_recipe.html', context)
```

create_recipe.html file:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label>recipe</label>
    <p>{{form}}</p>


    <label>ingredients</label>
    {% for form in formset %}
        
        <ul>
            <label>name</label>
            <li>{{ form.name }}</li>
            <label>quantity</label>
            <li>{{ form.quantity }}</li>
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" class="button-33" role="button">
    </div>
</form>
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: When I printed out request.method I can see 'GET' in console. why is it like that ?

Comment: Set the action to the HTML form like this: `action=""`, it might help

Comment: didn't help.....

Comment: Can you try: `curl -X POST -F "test2=test2" -F "test=test" http://127.0.0.1:8000/path/to/view/`? Django should throw up a CSRF error because it receives a POST request. If it does, the issue is likely in your HTML somewhere.

Comment: yeah it threw a lot of code with message: <p>In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when
  <a
  href="https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/csrf/">Django’s
  CSRF mechanism</a> has not been used correctly.  For POST forms, you need to
  ensure:</p>

Comment: Yes! that's good. Honestly, I can't really see the error. What I would do is, delete the form, start over, first create the parent form, finish that, make sure it works. Then get started on formsets. Or maybe even start with an empty form, a submit button and a token, then submitting only that, before working on anything else.

Comment: Do you have an `include` or `extends` in your `create_recipe.html`? There might be another `<form>` tag before the one you have already posted.

Comment: @Selcuk no i do not, it's the whole file

Answer (score 1):

> It is necessary to return HttpResponseRedirect after dealing with POST data, the tip is not specific to Django, it's a good web practice in general.

Also, try to maintain both GET and POST request separately, so try below view:

```py
def recipe_create_view(request):
    context = {}
    form="" # for the error of variable refrenced before assignment.
    IngredientFormset=""
    formset=""

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RecipeForm(request.POST)
        IngredientFormset = formset_factory(IngredientForm)
        formset = IngredientFormset(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            if formset.is_valid():
                form.save()
                print("made a recipe")
                
                for form in formset:
                    child = form.save(commit=False)
                    child.recipe = parent
                    child.save()
                    print("made a Ingredient")
                return redirect('some_success_path_name')
   
            else:
                print("formset is not valid")
        else:
            print("form is not valid")
    else: # GET method
        print("request method is GET")
        form = RecipeForm()
        IngredientFormset = formset_factory(IngredientForm)
        formset = IngredientFormset()
        context['form'] = form
        context['formset']  = formset

        

    return render(request, 'recipes/create_recipe.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

add `action` in your HTML form and `POST` in small case.

```
<form action="/your_backend_url_to_view/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label>recipe</label>
    <p>{{form}}</p>


    <label>ingredients</label>
    {% for form in formset %}
        
        <ul>
            <label>name</label>
            <li>{{ form.name }}</li>
            <label>quantity</label>
            <li>{{ form.quantity }}</li>
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" class="button-33" role="button">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: No, django always takes current page route if action not specified or if its like empty string such as `action=''` refer my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73287023/17562044) answer for further clarification and also POST is generally written in Capital case, it's the best way.